# How to add subtitles to the Animate CC HTML5 canvas video component

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I am working on **Animate CC** and want to have a **subtitle** for the **video component**. Would anyone be able to help me out?

Comment: [Have you checked this link?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see any mention of adding subtitle to Animate CC for video components